# syntax error while compiling SQLite DB (creating a table) whats wrong with my query?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INFO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_DOCNAME + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_SYMP + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_DIGNO + " TEXT " +
            COLUMN_MEDS + " TEXT " +
            ");";
     db.execSQL(query);
```

What is wrong with this? Getting the AndroidRuntime:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:                                  
                 near "date": syntax error: ,
 while compiling: CREATE TABLE info(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                   date TEXT 
                   docName TEXT symp TEXT digno TEXT meds TEXT );
```

Error.

Please help

Comment: comma `,` missing after every column datatype

Answer (score 1):

You have comma missing in the query after each column, change the query string as below:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INFO + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_DOCNAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_SYMP + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_DIGNO + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_MEDS + " TEXT " +
        ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma . Add it .

Comment: thanks, later on i figured out my stupid mistake, thanks again